# When trying to create a homegroup Windows 10 does not recognize that the network is private

Tags: windows-7, networking, home-networking, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1511

Want to create a homegroup on Windows 10 Pro (version 1511, build 10586.36, upgraded from Windows 7). Network and sharing center tells the network is private, but during homegroup creation I get message that it is not, and the homegroup cannot be created (please click on screenshots below if you need to enlarge). I never tried to create a homegroup before, so cannot tell whether this is specific to this particular version of the system...

Does anybody have similar experience? Looks like a bug, where and how to report it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Googling around I found that there might be some incompatibility with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and indeed when I uninstalled it I was able to create the homegroup.

I am not going to accept this answer however, as I hope there might be a solution which does not require to give up on using VirtualBox (or anything else, for that matter).

Comment: I don’t have Windows 10, so I cannot test. Did you try removing all VirtualBox network interfaces? They’re not required for NAT or Bridged Networking.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for the interesting suggestion, will try it. I only need virtualbox for Sage, most likely it can do without any networking.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, with both VMWare Workstation and Oracle VirtualBox installed. Disabling all virtual interfaces did not help. Removing the VirtualBox ones (only possible from inside VB) also did not help (plus, I need those for emulators, which are mostly VirtualBox based).  Uninstalling VB 5.0.12 fixed it though.